# '"SDL.h" no such file or directory found' when compiling

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

Here's a piece of my current Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu++11 `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL_mixer
```

I have libsdl installed properly, SDL.h is in /usr/include/sdl where it belongs, but it just won't compile. I also have the line `#include "SDL.h"` in my .h files, but still no go.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the header file is `/usr/include/sdl/SDL.h` and your code has:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

You need to either fix your code:

```
#include "sdl/SDL.h"
```

Or tell the preprocessor where to find include files:

```
CFLAGS = ... -I/usr/include/sdl ...
```

Answer (score 68):

For [Simple Direct Media Layer 2](https://www.libsdl.org/) (SDL2), after installing it on Ubuntu 16.04 via:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

I used the header:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

and the compiler linker command:

```
-lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Additionally, you may also want to install:

```
apt-get install libsdl2-image-dev  
apt-get install libsdl2-mixer-dev  
apt-get install libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

With these headers:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>
```

and the compiler linker commands:

```
-lSDL2_image 
-lSDL2_ttf 
-lSDL2_mixer
```

Comment: On linux, simply change `#include <SDL.h> ` to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h> ` fixed it, of course on compiling need `-lSDL2` flag.

Comment: In mac , get it using homebrew : brew install sdl2

Answer (score 9):

header file lives at

```
/usr/include/SDL/SDL.h

       __OR__

/usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h  #  for SDL2
```

in your c++ code pull in this header using

```
#include <SDL.h>

       __OR__

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>    // for SDL2
```

you have the correct usage of

```
sdl-config --cflags --libs

       __OR__

sdl2-config --cflags --libs   #  sdl2
```

which will give you

```
-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL

       __OR__

-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
-lSDL2
```

at times you may also see this usage which works for a standard install

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl

       __OR__

pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2   #  sdl2
```

which supplies you with

```
-D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL -lSDL

       __OR__

-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2   #  SDL2
```

Comment: Note: your correction on his usage of `sdl-config --clfags --libs` is false for SDL2.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog I updated to show both SDL and SDL@

Answer (score 7):

Most times SDL is in `/usr/include/SDL`. If so then your `#include <SDL.h>` directive is wrong, it should be `#include <SDL/SDL.h>`.

An alternative for that is adding the `/usr/include/SDL` directory to your include directories. To do that you should add `-I/usr/include/SDL` to the compiler flags...

If you are using an IDE this should be quite easy too...

Answer (score 3):

the simplest idea is to add pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 while compiling the code.

`` g++ file.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` ``

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar case and I couldn't use [StackAttack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4513646/stackattack)s solution as he's referring to SDL2 which is for the legacy code I'm using too new.

Fortunately our friends from [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/786301/363916) had something similar:

[Download SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php)

```
tar xvf SDL-1.2.tar.gz
cd SDL-1.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```