# Difference between #include"SDL/SDL.h" and #include"SDL.h"

Tags: sdl

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 . The compiler I am using is gcc and my IDE is CodeBlocks . I am working with SDL under C/C++ . When I include **"SDL/SDL.h"** , the program gets compiled and the output is displayed . But including **"SDL.h"** gives an error :

> fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
>   |=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Also there are 2 **SDL.h** files in **/usr/include** -
One is **/usr/include/SDL/SDL.h**
Other one is **/usr/include/SDL.h**

What is the difference between both the header files and why is only one path working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have 2 copies of SDL.h or what that is, but does this help? ['"SDL.h" no such file or directory found' when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488775/sdl-h-no-such-file-or-directory-found-when-compiling)

If you made a copy you should delete it.

Comment: I tried installing it 2 times . I think few remnants of the first failed installation were left in the folder . Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 1):

#include points to the folder "MinGW\include". Some people move their whole SDL folder there, so SDL.h is located in "SDL\SDL.h". Others just move their SDL.h to their include folder, meaning that they just need to use "SDL.h"

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

looks for a file named myheader.h while this:

```
#include "MyFolder\myheader.h"
```

looks for a file named myheader.h inside a folder named MyFolder