# GCC extern libraries

Tags: c, gcc, opengl, g++, sdl-2

Informations: 
OS: Windows 10 
Compiler: MinGW gcc 
Language: C 
SDL & OpenGL are already installed

When i try to compile the test file , i receive this error:

```
gcc test.c -o test
teste.c:1:10: fatal error: SDL2: No such file or directory
1 | #include <SDL2>
  |          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The test file content is:

```
#include <SDL2>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Testing");
}
```

This is my problem, help me pls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940896/14215102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the SDL header you need to use `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` instead of `#include <SDL2>`.

Comment: Or `#include <SDL.h>` depending on how your include paths are set up. IIRC the tutorial recommends `<SDL.h>`.